# custom search for holiday rental wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, plugins

I'm new to WP. I have decided to start holiday rental website and the theme I purchased is not a real estate theme and therefore has only the basis wp search.

I was hoping some one can help me to add this feature to my site. the fields I'm looking for are:

check in date - via calendar 
check out date - via calendar
no of people

I have not found a plugin either.

Thanks in advance